# Why #if 0 vs #if (1 > 1)?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I am working with a legacy code and found this:

```
#if (1 > 1)
//define some function
#endif
```

Not sure, how this can be any different from the more typical `#if 0`, to comment out the code? Any thoughts?

Comment: Probably, initiallly there were some other things than `1`s.. And then they gradually mutated. No, there is no difference.

Comment: Here's a wild guess. I often use `#if 0` to disable sections of code during development/debugging. Before releasing said code, I grep for `#if 0` to make sure that everything's back to normal. So I would use something other than `#if 0` for a block of code that needs to be disabled through multiple release cycles. However, I my case it's `#ifdef something_that_cant_possibly_be_defined`.

Comment: Change it to `#if (!!(1 > 1) != 1)` - mysteries are fun.

Comment: Well, inspired by @user3386109 I can come up with another crazy idea: You can number the disabled blocks (for identification) by `#if (1<1)`, `#if (2<2)` and so on...

Comment: Thanks all, the reason I asked this question cuz I believe there is a purpose to everything even if it is hidden. Not sure though if this applies to programming :)

Comment: @MIbrah If you replace the "*purpose*" by "*reason*" I could even agree with you. But it is not necessarily a good reason...

Comment: There are lots of strange superstitions about the preprocessor, this looks like one of the more bizarre ones.  It certainly has no well-defined special meaning (that is, other than it's truly equivalent to `#if 0`), so your guess is as good as ours...

Comment: Once I have seen a snippet of a C code hiding a [brainf@ck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) program in it.  `#if (1 > 1)` is hiding one BF instruction in it...

Comment: Some IDEs use syntax highlighting for `#if 0` specifically

Comment: Could it also be the result of some automatic code generation, where the original produced code was something like `#if SOME_TAG > 1` that then degenerated to `#if 1> 1`?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Both expressions are false, so the code is never compiled.

Here are potential explanations for why the programmer did not want to use the obvious `#if 0` preprocessor directive to disable a section of code:

- the programmer did not want `grep '#if 0'` to find his code snippet.
- the local coding conventions disallow `#if 0` and possibly enforce this rule with a script.  The programmer found a contorted workaround.
- some programmer's editors (eg `vim`) colorize `#if 0` sections as comments, using a different preprocessor expression defeats this.
- the programmer might have thought a boolean expression was required after `#if`.  The use of parentheses supports this explanation, but only the programmer can tell.
- the original code had `#if (OPTION > 1)` and `OPTION` was changed to `1` with a `sed` script or some other global text replacement method.
- the programmer may have wanted to attract the next reader's attention. Either for a humorous purpose or some other obscure goal.  Goal achieved in this case.
- as noted in some of the comments, this could be a lame attempt at obfuscating the code, to increase job security... For this purpose, I suggest the *gets* operator: `#if (0 <- 1)`  or the *crawling adder*: `#if (1 <~~ 1)`.

Comment: @user4581301: I'm not sure how this would buy *employment insurance*, but I shall add *reader warning*.

Answer (score 2):

I think the the  `(1 > 1)` acts as a comment for the reader. It is a smiley or some other emoticon!  :-)

It would also have been possible to write `(0>0)` or similar.

Comment: `0v0` == owl, `=^.^=` == cat

Comment: @cat I doubt the `=^.^= == cat` version will ever work, but you can get similar behaviour if you modify the owl example to `#if (OvO != owl)`

Comment: You just need a struct named `=^` with a member `^=`... oh, this is C. :P (I don't think `0v0` is valid C syntax either.)

Comment: @cat That's why I used `O`-s instead of zeroes. `Ov0` would also work thou.

Comment: But the `0`s get little dots inside them in this monospace font c: